# React/Redux - Handling errors and error codes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am wondering what is the best way for me to be handling errors, and when I should be using error codes in response from my API in conjunction with an errors object.

I have just started building a multi-part form in react, every time a user moves onto the next step in the form I am sending a request to the API to validate the data before moving onto the next step, and sending back a response of true/false with an errors object if they exist.

My question is, when I am returning generic errors, e.g:

```
if( hasErr == true ) {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        errors: errorsObject
    });
}
```

Should I be sending a status of 200 back, or should I be sending back a response with an error code somewhere in the 400 range?

Currently on the client side when I am recieving a response, my basic redux action looks like this:

```
this.props.createlistingAction(this.state).then(

    (res) => {

        if( res.payload.success == true ) {
            console.log('Success!');
        } else {
            console.log('We have errors!');

            this.setState({ errors: res.payload.errors });
        }

        console.log(res);
        //this.props.history.push('/'),
    },
    (err) =>  { // error
        console.log(err.response);
        this.setState({errors: err.response.data.errors, isLoading: false});
    }

);
```

Is it ok to be handling errors like this? Or if you do suggest I send back a 400 error response, how should I be getting these errors when the payload only contains a generic error "Error: Request failed with status code 400 at createError"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also return a content with a status code different by 200.
So you should easily return the HTTP Status Code related to the error and the error details in the body of your response.

Comment: Yes this is how I am currently handling things, sending back a response of 200, and picking up the errors in the body of the response, which appears to work fine. But I am asking, is this the correct way of doing things, or should I be sending back an error code - and if so how to pull errors from the response.

Comment: I've already answered you. It's possible to send a body response regardless of the status code you're sending.
The correct way is to send the response throught a correct status code!